# Word or phrase for something big that causes curiosity and starts a never-ending quest

Tags: phrase-requests

I am stuck writing this sentence:

> Relics such as Fortran, B, D and other programming languages continue to stay alive, stories of programming languages in the graveyard, and those that spurred magic have antecedent the continues quest of improving programming.

---

**EDIT: *Clarity*.**

Think of this as a battle cry among programming language developers. In this battle cry, stories of both success, and failures emerge overtime and historically, nevertheless, the journey is not even complete or done. Essentially, events, programming languages in the graveyard, and programming languages that made magic and allowed some companies to achieve technology never seen before, the combination of all of this has thus, "......" **the continuous quest of improving programming**.

I am trying to make the reader, from also previous text and stories discussed in the text, to understand that, technologies that left a MARK in an industry or across industries as a result of a different programming language have caused: **a *curiosity* and *quest* to build even better programming languages that can *move* industries forward.**

I HOPE THIS IS CLEAR ENOUGH.

Comment: There are a number of grammar mistakes in this sentence, which may distract people from the question at hand.

Comment: In *... stories of programming languages in the graveyard, and those that spurred magic have [a word here] the continuous quest of improving programming*, the word may be [revolutionize](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revolutionize).

Comment: @alphabet, what grammar mistakes are there?

Comment: @AlixBlaine The word "continues" doesn't make sense in that context; I think you mean "continued" or "continuous." The verbs "spurred" and "conjured" are also quite odd in that context, making me unsure of the intended meaning.

Comment: @AlixBlaine  "...have ***ushered***  the continuous quest of improving programming." Would that work for your intended meaning?

Comment: German, as usual, has the right expression: _bahnbrechende Erfindung_.

Comment: @JohnLawler **English**!

Comment: Could someone please diagram this sentence? I have no idea what each part is doing

Comment: Can you explain how anything in the exposition is related to the Question?

Comment: "instigate" may work for the "...." (example: *How can we develop digital technologies that are responsible and instigate progress?*).

Comment: It's a *renaissance* of sorts, but your FITB sentence is just asking for a verb, like *driven,* preceded by *has.*

Answer (score 1):

[***Usher in***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/usher-in)

"to be at the start of a new period, especially when important changes or new things happen, or to cause important changes to start happening"

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia...

> *A [**bellwether**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellwether) is a leader or an indicator of trends*
> ...
> *Sociologists apply the term in the active sense to **a person or group of people who tend to create, influence, or set trends**.*

Answer (score 0):

Something new can win **mindshare** and then its popularity (e.g. rate of adoption) can snowball. Though that describes the process, but it is not a name for the thing that wins mindshare, you might be able to adapt your paragraph by modifying the sentence accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Watershed**, besides geophysically meaning the ridge that separates two water basins, figuratively means

> an event or period marking a turning point in a course of action or state of affairs: these works mark a watershed in the history of music. (NOAD)

After a watershed moment, all the metaphorical water flows in a new direction. After one company has made a specific technological advance, say, no real competitor can continue operating in the previous ways.

Comment: I guess the OP is looking for a verb.

Comment: I confess I am very confused by the use of "something" in the title, the choice of "conjure" as the stand-in, and the general grammar of the post

Answer (score 0):

***Redefine*** is word that might work here, describing a fundamental change to something which is carried forward into the future. You could say something has "redefined the quest for improved programming", indicating that it caused a big change which was widely adopted and highly impactful.

Answer (score 0):

**[Lodestar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lodestar)**, although it's a noun, fits the desired meaning - "an example or principle that people want to follow".  To quote an example that Cambridge gives:

> The fundamental concept of disease as a result of population exposures to environmental pathogens has served for generations as the *lodestar* of preventive medicine.